# Robotic arm object/item pile relocation?

Tags: robotic-arm, path-planning, automation

I am somewhat new to robotics. As such, I might be unaware of the correct terms or lingo that I need to use. I am trying to find relevant information on autonomous robotic arm operations specifically in terms of relocating piles of semi-indistinguishable objects. The pile could be anything from a pile of stones, pebbles, sticks, etc.

I am trying to find literature/ examples of similar operations that have been performed in order to get things started on my end. (I have already tried in a simulated environment - gazebo and VREP)

I am able to understand how to autonomously detect and relocate a single inanimate object from point A to point B, but when it comes to piles of the said object I am not sure how to start with the pile. The simulated arm has the capability to cluster pick multiple objects at the same time. (like a clamp)

I have tried to look up online to see if I could find any related articles or research papers but I have been hitting a dead end. Not exactly even sure what I should be searching as the common terms I have used here didn't work.

Any advise, articles, papers, or points in the correct direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: to move the pile of objects, do you want to use tweezers or use a shovel?

Comment: @jsotola: An arm with a tweezer type end would make more sense in my case since the idea is to be able to relocate the pile to anywhere in 3d space.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Equaltrace, but I'm afraid that opinion polls are [discouraged on stack exchange](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/). We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of advantages & disadvantages for different options are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: @Ben Hello Ben. Thanks for the information. After going through the links listed by you, I believe my question falls under the "a specific robotics design problem" and "the theory and simulation of robotic systems" as listed on the page [link](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I am inquiring about a very specific robotics problem, about which I have found little information online or in literature. I don't think my question is polling for the benefits, advantages, or disadvantages of anything in particular. Kindly advise.